# How do you switch between clean and distortion on a virtual amp setup?

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I'm new to virtual amp simulations and I was wondering how do you switch between a dirty and clean tone midway into recording a song as you don't have a footswitch or a pedal unlike through a normal amp.

Comment: Is the virtual amp a software program running on a computer or a mobile device like a smartphone, or is it a dedicated hardware effects device?

Comment: Look for a Bypass button. Read the manual of the plugin. Read about automation in the manual of your DAW/sequencer.

Answer (score 3):

You typically will have a virtual footswitch - most of the virtual amps I use do allow switching from dirty to clean, or switching distortion on and off.

Many will also allow a real footswitch to be used.